# How to disable certain field with Databinder in Spring

Tags: spring, data-binding

I've been trying to use the setDisallowedFields inside the DataBinder to disable the association of request parameter to my object without any success.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        System.out.println(dataBinder.getValidator());
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("customerId");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Customer home(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model m) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.join(bindingResult.getSuppressedFields(), ","));
        System.out.println(bindingResult.hasErrors());
        return customer;
    }
}
```

My object:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    private String firstName;

    private String customerId;

    // getter and setter not included
}
```

And my config files:

WebConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.example.controller")
  public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {}
```

WebAppInitializer.java:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
    }
}
```

The field validation (NotNull, size) are well verified and hasErrors is set. But when I submit a customerId, the value is injected into the object without warning or error.

Is there any extra step to implement this feature?

Thanks

Comment: The `DataBinder` only works for form objects i.e. `@ModelAttributes`. However you are using `@RequestBody` and as such the data binder isn't used and you will have to solve it in your JSON mapper.

Comment: Are you using Jackson as JSON library?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Jackson.